# Set an HTML5 data array using jQuery vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, variables

I've been struggling with this for awhile now and can't seem to find the correct syntax.

If I have these variables declared in JS:

```
var width = 300,
    height = 200,
    time = 100;
```

And some html:

```
<div class="target">Target</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to set those vars as an html5 data array onto the target div like so:

```
<div class="target" data-stuff='["300","200","100"]'>Target</div>
```

Comment: The below answer is fine, but I'd recommend doing data-width, data-height, data-time... it's less parsing for when you want to work with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert data-attributes into your HTML content, you'd need to use the `.attr()` method:

```
$('.target').attr('data-stuff', '['+[width, height, time].toString()+']');
```

To just set the data to the element, without needing to actually set an attribute in the HTML, use `.data()`:

```
$('.target').data('stuff', [width, height, time]);
```

and to retrieve the value of either of those two, use:

```
$('.target').data('stuff')
```

This will return the array `[300, 200, 100]` in both cases. A demo of this script can be seen [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rcws/1/). Just open your console (In Chrome: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, in Internet Explorer: <kbd>F12</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) and you'll see 2 arrays at the bottom there.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
a = $(".target").data("stuff");

var width = a[0],
    height = a[1],
    time = a[2];
```

**Update**

If you want to set the variables in the html data attribute, just:

```
$(".target").data("stuff", [width, height, time]);
```

Comment: I'm testing in a jsFiddle, and it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something incorrectly here? http://jsfiddle.net/9rcws/

Comment: Sergio, I think you misunderstood the question. The question is how to set the data-stuff attribute, not how to set a var with the data-stuff attribute's values.

Comment: @SergioAristizábal You typoed there, there are now 2 commas after the `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var width = 300,
height = 200,
time = 100;

$(".target").data("myarray", [width, height, time]);

console.log($(".target").data("myarray"));
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8h5W/)